# PayPal NVP API error : Sorry, we can’t complete your purchase at this time

Tags: paypal

I'm using PayPal NVP API. 
When I use sandbox account and sandbox API_ENDPOINT, it works well. 
When I use production account and production API_ENDPOINT, it is successfully redirecting to PayPal, but after user input paypal username and password and submit, it shows: "Sorry, we can’t complete your purchase at this time. Please return to the merchant’s website and choose another way to pay."
I have created an app in developer.paypal.com, but still get this error.
Any one can help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the buyer side funding source. If you are still persisting the same issue kindly file a ticket to PayPal MTS.

Comment: I changed the buyer account(sandbox)and still see the error, I also tried to create another sandbox account but I got an error.

Comment: Having the same issue, Tried to different developer accounts with different set of merchant (sandbox) and buyers (sandbox) accounts. Always getting "Sorry, we can’t complete your purchase at this time. Please return to the merchant’s website and choose another way to pay."

Comment: same issue here, any solution