# signature request API wrong url

Tags: paypal

When I do a Paypal API signature request under business profile, the generated api is using my old website ---whateverAPI.my-old-website.com
I've updated all of my business information and see no instances of the old url in my paypal account or the developer or sandbox accounts.
I do not have the old login information for developer area where I created the original API information as it was changed to my new login/business.
I need to change the URL associated with my account so the api generated has the apicode.new-website.com
I know this is a low level expertise for most of you compared to what you are coding but I am completely stuck and have tried everything I can think of.
Thanks for taking the time to read!

Comment: My apologies, corrected it to Paypal

Comment: No problem. Now you have a better chance of attracting the right person to your question. (Not me, I don't use the paypal api).

Answer (score 1):

When the API is first requested on an account, it is generated based on the email address associated with the account at the time.  Even if you remove the email address and request new API credentials, it will still use that original email address.  There is no need for concern, you only set this in your API call or in your shopping cart to use.  Buyers are not going to see it or anything, and it's not something you would regularly share or have to use all that often.  Once you set it in your code, you don't really mess with it again unless you need to set up the API credentials again.

Comment: Thank you!! That makes sense. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please can you help us on this error: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661253/paypal-nvp-api-error-sorry-we-can-t-complete-your-purchase-at-this-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661253/paypal-nvp-api-error-sorry-we-can-t-complete-your-purchase-at-this-time). Why do you think we are getting this error ?