# How to distinguish between hosted buttons and non hosted buttons in the IPN listener

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

How to distinguish between hosted buttons and non hosted buttons in the IPN listener ?

the hosted buttons created by paypal has a `<form>` variable that is unique it's something like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="FOOBARFOOBAR">
```

However when I checked the IPN [variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) I can't see the `hosted_button_id` variable returned by PayPal.

Anyone can create a custom payment with the same values a hosted payment has, like

```
"mc_gross":"400.00"
"mc_fee":"19.90",
"mc_currency":"USD",
"business":"someone@example.com"
"item_name":"the same name as the hosted button",
"item_number":"same_number"
```

**How do I know in my IPN listener script that this purchase is done from a hosted button or not ?**

Comment: You don't. The hosted button ID isn't returned. You have to do like the IPN samples do, and ensure your own database has such a product at such a price before actioning the purchase. You could use the `custom` field to return the hosted button ID, but then you can't use it for anything else.

Comment: thank you very much. If you have time can you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661253/paypal-nvp-api-error-sorry-we-can-t-complete-your-purchase-at-this-time)